# How to edit Visual Studio Code settings on macOS Big Sur

Tags: applications, big-sur

In Big Sur the *Applications* folder is on a read-only filesystem.

1. What is the path to the newly installed *Visual Studio Code* ? I saw this

`_/private/var/folders/dy/pmwkncg14wd3hhqpf8mhp6p80000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E7E6FA9F-1C3F-4F04-A836-28299414ACBB/d/Visual Studio Code.app`

I'm hoping there were something more approachable available..

2. How can I update the *settings.json* and *keybindings.json* in there?

Comment: You would use the regular menu entry.  You did not install VS Code in the read-only System Applications folder.  You installed it in the read-write folder mounted under Volumes.

Comment: @MarcWilson. I want to copy both files from another machine - which probably means not to use the menu entry ?  What is the directory where this is located that is human reproducible - not that hex encoded one in the question?

Comment: I have no idea where you got that.    `/Library/Application Support/Code/User`  Same place it's always been.

Comment: Maybe you looking for functionality of [settings sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) available in VS Code:  "Settings Sync lets you share your Visual Studio Code configurations such as settings, keybindings, and installed extensions across your machines so you are always working with your favorite setup."

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I am aware of sync - it works well. But no I am wondering how to copy the config files directly.  Big Sur did not let me do that

Comment: @MarcWilson already pointed the location of settings.json and keyboard.json files and while I am not committed to replace these files nothing prevented me to modify them and create new dummy file in that location. Therefore I am pretty sure that there is no problem of replacing them as well.

Comment: I gave you an incorrect path.  `~/Library` , not `/Library`.

Comment: @MarcWilson Yea that was easy to figure out: but I had gotten it were a link to another location on a "read-only filesystem" thus my follow-up

Comment: ~/Library is not on the read-only volume.  You seem to think you need to modify the app bundle for some reason.  Which isn't on the read-only volume either.